# Julia: convert Array to DataFrame with Column Names

Tags: dataframe, julia, rename

I am trying to convert an array to a Julia dataframes and adding column names. Unfortunately, the solutions that I found doesn't seem to work....

```
using DataFrames

x = rand(4, 3)
df = convert(DataFrame, x)

# This doesn't work:

rename!(df, ["Col_A", "Col_B", "Col_C"])
names(df) = ["Col_A", "Col_B", "Col_C"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
using DataFrames

x = rand(4, 3)
df = DataFrame(x)
names!(df, [:Col_A, :Col_B, :Col_C])
```

or simply this:

```
DataFrame(x, [:Col_A, :Col_B, :Col_C])
```

Notice that column names have to be `Symbol`. If you have them as strings you can convert them like this `Symbol.(["Col_A", "Col_B", "Col_C"])`.